# Data Dictionary for DB2

Tags: db2

How can i fetch information in db2 Database.

- Datetime the current object was created or changed
- Object name
- Object owner
- User who created or update the object
- Data definition language script
- List of data element (column) names and details
- Key order for all the elements (which can be possible keys)
- Information about indexes and other attributes
- Relationships
- Changes
- Extended properties

Can anyone please help me if it is possible in DB2.

Comment: Do you need this DB2 info on an `IBM i` system?

Comment: @Nifriz: Yes......Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a full list of System tables, from IBM Knowledge Center:

```
SYSCATALOGS
The SYSCATALOGS view contains one row for each relational database that a user can connect to. The following table describes the columns in the SYSCATALOGS view.

SYSCHKCST
The SYSCHKCST view contains one row for each check constraint in the SQL schema. The following table describes the columns in the SYSCHKCST view.

SYSCOLAUTH
The SYSCOLAUTH view contains one row for every privilege granted on a column. Note that this catalog view cannot be used to determine whether a user is authorized to a column because the privilege to use a column could be acquired through a group user profile or special authority (such as *ALLOBJ). Furthermore, the privilege to use a column is also acquired through privileges granted on the table.

SYSCOLUMNS
The SYSCOLUMNS view contains one row for every column of each table and view in the SQL schema (including the columns of the SQL catalog).

SYSCOLUMNS2
The SYSCOLUMNS2 view contains one row for every column of each table and view in the SQL schema (including the columns of the SQL catalog).

SYSCOLUMNSTAT
The SYSCOLUMNSTAT view contains one row for every column in a table partition or table member that has a column statistics collection. If the table is a distributed table, the partitions that reside on other database nodes are not contained in this catalog view.

SYSCONTROLS
The SYSCONTROLS view contains one row for each row permission or column mask defined by the CREATE PERMISSION or CREATE MASK statements.

SYSCONTROLSDEP
The SYSCONTROLSDEP view records the dependencies of row permissions and column masks.

SYSCST
The SYSCST view contains one row for each constraint in the SQL schema.

SYSCSTCOL
The SYSCSTCOL view records the columns on which constraints are defined. There is one row for every column in a unique, primary key, and check constraint and the referencing columns of a referential constraint.

SYSCSTDEP
The SYSCSTDEP view records the tables on which constraints are defined.

SYSFIELDS
The SYSFIELDS view contains one row for every column that has a field procedure.

SYSFUNCS
The SYSFUNCS view contains one row for each function created by the CREATE FUNCTION statement.

SYSHISTORYTABLES
The SYSHISTORYTABLES view contains one row for every history table, whether or not the history table is part of an established versioning relationship.

SYSINDEXES
The SYSINDEXES view contains one row for every index in the SQL schema created using the SQL CREATE INDEX statement, including indexes on the SQL catalog.

SYSINDEXSTAT
The SYSINDEXSTAT view contains one row for every SQL index partition.

SYSJARCONTENTS
The SYSJARCONTENTS table contains one row for each class defined by a jarid in the SQL schema.

SYSJAROBJECTS
The SYSJAROBJECTS table contains one row for each jarid in the SQL schema.

SYSKEYCST
The SYSKEYCST view contains one or more rows for each UNIQUE KEY, PRIMARY KEY, or FOREIGN KEY in the SQL schema. There is one row for each column in every unique or primary key constraint and the referencing columns of a referential constraint.

SYSKEYS
The SYSKEYS view contains one row for every column of an index in the SQL schema, including the keys for the indexes on the SQL catalog.

SYSMQTSTAT
The SYSMQTSTAT view contains one row for every materialized table partition.

SYSPACKAGE
The SYSPACKAGE view contains one row for each SQL package in the SQL schema.

SYSPACKAGEAUTH
The SYSPACKAGEAUTH view contains one row for every privilege granted on a package. Note that this catalog view cannot be used to determine whether a user is authorized to a package because the privilege to use a package could be acquired through a group user profile or special authority (such as *ALLOBJ).

SYSPACKAGESTAT
The SYSPACKAGESTAT view contains one row for each SQL package in the SQL schema.

SYSPACKAGESTMTSTAT
The SYSPACKAGESTMTSTAT view contains one row for each SQL statement in every SQL package.

SYSPARMS
The SYSPARMS table contains one row for each parameter of a procedure created by the CREATE PROCEDURE statement or function created by the CREATE FUNCTION statement. The result of a scalar function and the result columns of a table function are also returned.

SYSPARTITIONDISK
The SYSPARTITIONDISK view contains one row for every disk unit used to store data of every table partition or table member. If the table is a distributed table, the partitions that reside on other database nodes are not contained in this catalog view. They are contained in the catalog views of the other database nodes.

SYSPARTITIONINDEXDISK
The SYSPARTITIONINDEXDISK view contains one row for every disk unit used to store the index data of every table partition or table member. If the index is a distributed index, the partitions that reside on other database nodes are not contained in this catalog view. They are contained in the catalog views of the other database nodes.

SYSPARTITIONINDEXES
The SYSPARTITIONINDEXES view contains one row for every index built over a table partition or table member. If the table is a distributed table, the indexes over partitions that reside on other database nodes are not contained in this catalog view. They are contained in the catalog views of the other database nodes.

SYSPARTITIONINDEXSTAT
The SYSPARTITIONINDEXSTAT view contains one row for every index built over a table partition or table member. Indexes that share another index’s binary tree are not included. If the table is a distributed table, the indexes over partitions that reside on other database nodes are not contained in this catalog view. They are contained in the catalog views of the other database nodes.

SYSPARTITIONMQTS
The SYSPARTITIONMQTS view contains one row for every materialized table built over a table partition or table member. If the table is a distributed table, the materialized tables over partitions that reside on other database nodes are not contained in this catalog view. They are contained in the catalog views of the other database nodes.

SYSPARTITIONSTAT
The SYSPARTITIONSTAT view contains one row for every table partition or table member. If the table is a distributed table, the partitions that reside on other database nodes are not contained in this catalog view. They are contained in the catalog views of the other database nodes.

SYSPERIODS
The SYSPERIODS view contains one row for every period defined for a temporal table in an SQL schema.

SYSPROCS
The SYSPROCS view contains one row for each procedure created by the CREATE PROCEDURE statement.

SYSPROGRAMSTAT
The SYSPROGRAMSTAT view contains one row for each program, service program, and module that contains SQL statements.

SYSPROGRAMSTMTSTAT
The SYSPROGRAMSTMTSTAT view contains one row for each embedded SQL statement in a program, module, or service program.
SYSREFCST
The SYSREFCST view contains one row for each foreign key in the SQL schema.
SYSROUTINEAUTH
The SYSROUTINEAUTH view contains one row for every privilege granted on a routine. Note that this catalog view cannot be used to determine whether a user is authorized to a routine because the privilege to use a routine could be acquired through a group user profile or special authority (such as *ALLOBJ).

SYSROUTINEDEP
The SYSROUTINEDEP view records the dependencies of routines.
SYSROUTINES
The SYSROUTINES table contains one row for each procedure created by the CREATE PROCEDURE statement and each function created by the CREATE FUNCTION statement.

SYSSCHEMAAUTH
The SYSSCHEMAAUTH view contains one row for every privilege granted on a schema. Note that this catalog view cannot be used to determine whether a user is authorized to a schema because the privilege to use a schema could be acquired through a group user profile or special authority (such as *ALLOBJ).

SYSSCHEMAS
The SYSSCHEMAS view contains one row for every schema in the relational database.
SYSSEQUENCEAUTH
The SYSSEQUENCEAUTH view contains one row for every privilege granted on a sequence. Note that this catalog view cannot be used to determine whether a user is authorized to a sequence because the privilege to use a sequence could be acquired through a group user profile or special authority (such as *ALLOBJ).

SYSSEQUENCES
The SYSSEQUENCES view contains one row for every sequence object in the SQL schema.
SYSTABAUTH
The SYSTABAUTH view contains one row for every privilege granted on a table or view. Note that this catalog view cannot be used to determine whether a user is authorized to a table or view because the privilege to use a table or view could be acquired through a group user profile or special authority (such as *ALLOBJ).

SYSTABLEDEP
The SYSTABLEDEP view records the dependencies of materialized query tables.

SYSTABLEINDEXSTAT
The SYSTABLEINDEXSTAT view contains one row for every index that has at least one partition or member built over a table. If the index is over more than one partition or member, the statistics include all those partitions and members. If the table is a distributed table, the partitions that reside on other database nodes are not included. They are contained in the catalog views of the other database nodes.

SYSTABLES
The SYSTABLES view contains one row for every table, view or alias in the SQL schema, including the tables and views of the SQL catalog.

SYSTABLESTAT
The SYSTABLESTAT view contains one row for every table that has at least one partition or member. If the table has more than one partition or member, the statistics include all partitions and members. If the table is a distributed table, the partitions that reside on other database nodes are not included. They are contained in the catalog views of the other database nodes.

SYSTRIGCOL
The SYSTRIGCOL view contains one row for each column either implicitly or explicitly referenced in the WHEN clause or the triggered SQL statements of a trigger.

SYSTRIGDEP
The SYSTRIGDEP view contains one row for each object referenced in the WHEN clause or the triggered SQL statements of a trigger.

SYSTRIGGERS
The SYSTRIGGERS view contains one row for each trigger in an SQL schema.

SYSTRIGUPD
The SYSTRIGUPD view contains one row for each column identified in the UPDATE column list, if any.

SYSTYPES
The SYSTYPES table contains one row for each built-in data type and each distinct type and array type created by the CREATE TYPE statement.

SYSUDTAUTH
The SYSUDTAUTH view contains one row for every privilege granted on a type. Note that this catalog view cannot be used to determine whether a user is authorized to a type because the privilege to use a type could be acquired through a group user profile or special authority (such as *ALLOBJ).

SYSVARIABLEAUTH
The SYSVARIABLEAUTH view contains one row for every privilege granted on a global variable. Note that this catalog view cannot be used to determine whether a user is authorized to a global variable because the privilege to use a global variable could be acquired through a group user profile or special authority (such as *ALLOBJ).

SYSVARIABLEDEP
The SYSVARIABLEDEP table records the dependencies of variables.

SYSVARIABLES
The SYSVARIABLES table contains one row for each global variable.

SYSVIEWDEP
The SYSVIEWDEP view records the dependencies of views on tables, including the views of the SQL catalog.

SYSVIEWS
The SYSVIEWS view contains one row for each view in the SQL schema, including the views of the SQL catalog.

SYSXSROBJECTAUTH
The SYSXSROBJECTAUTH view contains one row for every privilege granted on an XML schema. Note that this catalog view cannot be used to determine whether a user is authorized to a XML schema because the privilege to use a XML schema could be acquired through a group user profile or special authority (such as *ALLOBJ).

XSRANNOTATIONINFO
The XSRANNOTATIONINFO table contains one row for each annotation in an XML schema to record the table and column information about the annotation.

XSROBJECTCOMPONENTS
The XSROBJECTCOMPONENTS table contains one row for each component (document) in an XML schema.

XSROBJECTHIERARCHIES
The XSROBJECTHIERARCHIES table contains one row for each component (document) in an XML schema to record the XML schema document hierarchy relationship.

XSROBJECTS
The XSROBJECTS table contains one row for each registered XML schema.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Db2 for i-series implements its catalog as many views and tables that you can query with SQL to get the answers you need.

Different Db2 server platforms implement their catalog in different schemas.
Db2 on z/OS implements its catalog tables in the SYSIBM schema.
Db2 on Linux/UnixWindows implements its catalog views in the SYSCAT schema (but also has underlying tables for some of those views in the SYSIBM schema)

As there are  many such views (for example [QSYS2.SYSTABLES](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatsystbls.htm)) , it is unwise to duplicate here the many documentation pages that are available in the product documentation at [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/db2/rbafzcatalog.htm), so use that page as the start for your search. You should learn which is the exact version of your i-series, and then choose that version on the page via the menu 'Change version of product' . Sometimes different versions have different catalog views, so choose the version that matches your server.

Comment: i am using v5.....