# SQL cross referencing

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

If I was to make a change to an object(possibly a table) , I want to find out via system catalog tables where this object is referenced/used. So what CatLog system table to check stored procedures? functions, triggers, constraints. Have I missed any?

Thanks for your help in advance,
JemRug

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57266435/data-dictionary-for-db2

Comment: That's perfect, are they different if you have a java client via JDBC etc?

Comment: How do deal with dynamic sql references, can you do a best guess approch in this area?

Comment: Not sure I follow - sounds like a SQL Code artefact - would the answer in this case qualify as a "dynamic sql reference" ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53196938/refer-to-table-name-dynamically-in-db2-400-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

to find the functions and procedures where a table is referenced, you can scan the `routine_definition` column of the `sysibm.routines` view for the table name. Use `regexp_instr` function to look for the pattern FROM|UPDATE|INSERT INTO followed by the table name.

```
with t1 as (                                                       
SELECT char(ROUTINE_SCHEMA,10) libname,                            
       char(ROUTINE_NAME,30) routine_name,                         
       cast(a.routine_definition as varchar(9999)) routine_defn    
FROM   sysibm.routines a                                           
where  routine_schema = 'YOURLIB'                                   
  ),  t2 as (                                                      
select  a.routine_name,                                            
   regexp_instr(a.routine_defn,                                    
        '(FROM|UPDATE|INSERT INTO)\s+YOUR_TABLE',1,1) pos,             
 a.routine_defn                                                    
from t1 a )                                                        
select  a.routine_name,  a.pos, substr(a.routine_defn,pos,20) text 
from      t2 a                                                     
where    a.pos > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ibm function
RELATED_OBJECTS SQL

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=services-related-objects-table-function